# On load testing my api for 2500 per second, following error came

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, load-testing

I have an api that reads count of rows in a table and then saves a particular data in that table.Db is mysql. On load testing my api for 2500 hits per second, communication link error came.Error is:

```
2019-08-01 18:28:26:478 [91b1bc2f1259de35/91b1bc2f1259de35] [http-nio-80-exec-149] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 5,235 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 5,235 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:482 [94a83dcaff8f64bf/94a83dcaff8f64bf] [http-nio-80-exec-160] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,962 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,962 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [17b1c2d0e038602d/17b1c2d0e038602d] [http-nio-80-exec-174] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,824 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,824 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:478 [c18b3bcfe063c93c/c18b3bcfe063c93c] [http-nio-80-exec-170] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,072 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,072 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:478 [06da8ae0c3f60282/06da8ae0c3f60282] [http-nio-80-exec-168] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,125 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,125 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [67ccdca788431e36/67ccdca788431e36] [http-nio-80-exec-179] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,893 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,893 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:478 [1f8fe32ba4ea4133/1f8fe32ba4ea4133] [http-nio-80-exec-127] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 766 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,286 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [690697c5aff7d7ba/690697c5aff7d7ba] [http-nio-80-exec-169] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,523 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,523 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [a77288b5347b2112/a77288b5347b2112] [http-nio-80-exec-177] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,903 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,903 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [61a6e4bbeedcdea1/61a6e4bbeedcdea1] [http-nio-80-exec-156] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,414 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,414 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:478 [a99d138ae705007d/a99d138ae705007d] [http-nio-80-exec-191] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,538 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,538 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:478 [9f5c21bbd7707b46/9f5c21bbd7707b46] [http-nio-80-exec-161] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,348 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,348 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [fbebe6351a9a638f/fbebe6351a9a638f] [http-nio-80-exec-158] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,775 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,775 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:482 [e9b3c26cf69f2c13/e9b3c26cf69f2c13] [http-nio-80-exec-164] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,615 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,615 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:478 [e0101aee3c7a1bb4/e0101aee3c7a1bb4] [http-nio-80-exec-172] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,951 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,951 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [d9655f8dd1f9e70f/d9655f8dd1f9e70f] [http-nio-80-exec-186] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,842 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,842 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:482 [c6fa3fdf7ec1dc3e/c6fa3fdf7ec1dc3e] [http-nio-80-exec-153] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 3,874 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 4,608 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:482 [8d46ab20a948fc91/8d46ab20a948fc91] [http-nio-80-exec-167] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,755 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2,755 milliseconds ago.
2019-08-01 18:28:26:500 [e01cf78be1b030d7/e01cf78be1b030d7] [http-nio-80-exec-154] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 142 - Communications link failure
```

Comment: It seems your database is rejecting connections to ir. Maybe it's overwhelmed due to the load.

Comment: yaa may be but I configured connection pooling to 50reads and 50 writes..

Comment: Does it work for e.g. 2000 and not for 2500? Or did you start with 2500? Can you lower the load and test again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [MySQL Communication Link Failure](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/mysql-communication-link-failure-214338032.html) article:

1. Make sure to set [Validation Query](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/setting-up-lightweight-validationquery-for-mysql-744527619.html)
2. Make sure to [monitor your MySQL server instance](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-monitor-mysql/) as it might be the case the MySQL server is overloaded and dies or runs into state when it cannot accept new network connections. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for this.

Actually if you cannot reproduce the situation for less amount of threads (virtual users) it means that MySQL database is the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) so you might want to [tune MySQL instance for better performance](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/performance/index.html) or even test it separately by using [JMeter's JDBC Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)